# Fix Format of values in table td

Tags: html, css

I have this code :

```
   <table width="105%" style="left: -13px;position: relative;"> 
               <tr style="line-height: 35px; " class='0'>
                 <td style="left: -15px;position: relative;">Nom et Prénom</td>
                 <td style="color: #90949c;"><input type="text" class="textedit" value="vbnvbn ">  </input> </td>
                 <td class="tdm" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a class="tdmod">Modifier</a> </td>
               </tr>
         </table>
```

the first td of every tr is not organized like others. so how to fix it without using `float:left`? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<td style="left: -15px;position: relative; text-align: left;">Nom et Prénom</td>
```